# Create a "real' second network interface on the fly for DHCP testing

Tags: dhcp, bridge

On several Linux remote hosts, I want to test the corresponding remote DHCP servers (the servers are on different hosts, and I don't have access to them).
I connect to these hosts with ssh, and don't want to reboot them, and don't want to modify eth0 configuration.

I know how to obtain some basic DHCP informations: `nmap  --script  broadcast-dhcp-discover`
This give some really usefull informations. But we deal with buggy DHCP servers so I want to setup a "real" network interface to test them on the long run.

If I use a network interface as eth0:1 then dhclient refuse to do the job:

```
ip addr add 192.168.0.123/24 label eth0:1 dev eth0
dhclient -v eth0:1
# --> dhclient displays: Bind socket to interface: No such device
```

I then tried to create a dummy network interface and bridge it. BUT this modify the configuration for eth0, which is not desired:

```
ip link add br0 type bridge         # create a bridge

# in one line, so the ssh connection is not lost (can additionnaly be wise
# to use "screen" but I currently do the tests on a local computer):
ip addr del 192.168.0.30/24 dev eth0; \
ip addr add 192.168.0.30/24 dev br0;  \
ip link set dev eth0 master br0;      \
ip link set dev br0 up

modprobe  dummy                     # create dummy0 
ip link set dev dummy0 master br0
```

Now I can have a DHCP lease for eth0: `dhclient -v eth0` works well.
But `dhclient -v dummy0` never get any DHCP lease (no error displayed).

--> how can I create a network interface correctly bridged to the physical network, without touching eth0 (appart for making eth0 part of the bridge)?